# Transparent AlertDialog Button Background

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I cannot change the white background of the buttons. I want transparent background that matches with the upper transparent background. I tried several methods but did not work. Is there any way to do it?

[image]

```
public void onNextClick() {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(AuthenticatorActivity.this);
        View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_user_info, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AuthenticatorActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);

        // setup a dialog window
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        })

        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // create an alert dialog
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        alert.show();
        alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.argb(0, 200, 200, 200)));
        alert.getWindow().setLayout(450, 450);


        Button btnSubmit = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        btnSubmit.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        Button btnCancel = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        btnCancel.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting `#00010000` to the buttons 'background' property in `R.layout.input_user_info`

Comment: The buttons are not in the xml. They are generated from the code.

Comment: @Rashed after testing your code. it's working on my phone, buttons are transparent

Comment: Where did you put the color code? There is no button background property in input_user_info.

Answer (score 0):

Add custom layout button to `R.layout.input_user_info` , and make it transparent, like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150"
    android:background="@drawable/abackground">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Cancel"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#c8000000"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b_submit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Submit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

On click event:

```
View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.input_user_info, null);
cancel_button = (Button)promptView.findViewById(R.id.b_cancel);
submit_button = (Button)promptView.findViewById(R.id.b_submit);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AuthenticatorActivity.this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
final AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             alert.cancel;
        }
    });
submit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //Do some thing

        }
    });
```

Layout will like this:
[image: Layout will like this]

Comment: xml code is fine but alertdialog does not support the above java code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instead

**XML :**

```
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

**Via Codes :**

```
 bSubmit.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

**OR you can create a drawable to manager click states :**

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid
            android:color="#757575" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"/>

    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >

        <solid
            android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"/>

    </shape>
</item>
```

hope it helps. happy codings.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `TextView`with `android:background="@null"`. If you want lines between `TextViews` you can add another views in your layout.